# TinyMCE v6 com funções customizadas e eventos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, tinymce

Estou com uma necessidade no tinyMCE, já passei várias vezes pela documentação mas não consegui achar uma solução.

Com o editor estou permitindo inserir `inputs` dentro do editor, o conteúdo salvo vai se tornar um formulário que poderá ser preenchido posteriormente por usuários.

Consegui fazer a inserção sem problema, porém como são campos personalizados (como tamanho, tipo de input, etc), seria bom ter a opção de editar este input depois de criado. Tentei adicionar um evento de `dblclick()` pra tentar abrir de novo a modal, mas sem sucesso (visto que roda dentro do iframe, qualquer função javascript/jquery que eu faça não irá alcançar o editor).

Alguém tem uma dica do que posso fazer? Tentei criar um plugin pra isso mas sem sucesso. Qualquer exemplo de plugin é exclusivamente por acesso via um botão de menu, não consegui de forma alguma criar um evento de escuta pros inputs diretamente.

Aqui um link do codepen [CodePen](https://codepen.io/EddaSistemas/pen/yLqvqbx)
No codepen só tem um botão que é pra adicionar input, que exemplifica como está funcionando no momento.

Meu javascript contém essas funções

```
<script>
edtInputText = `
  <div class="custom-panel">
   <label>Define um nome do campo <input id="iname" type="text" name="iname"></label>
   <label>Exemplo <input id="iexemp" type="text" name="iexemp"></label>
   <div class="inline">
     <label>Mínimo de caracteres <input id="imin" type="number" name="imin"></label>
     <label>Máximo de caracteres <input id="imax" type="number" name="imax"></label>
   </div>
  </div> `;

  let editorOpt = {
selector: '#editor',
plugins: [
  'advlist', 'anchor', 'autolink', 'fullscreen', 'help',
  'image', 'lists', 'link', 'media', 'preview', 'visualchars', 'pagebreak',
  'searchreplace', 'table', 'visualblocks', 'wordcount',     ],
images_file_types: 'png,jpg,svg,webp',
file_picker_types: 'file image media',
automatic_uploads: true,
inlinecss: true,
draggable_modal: true,
valid_elements: '@[id|class|style|onclick|ondblclick|contenteditable],sup[class|style],u[class|style],s[class|style],sub[class|style],span[class|style],table[class|style|colspan|rowspan],tr[class|style|colspan|rowspan],td[class|style|colspan|rowspan],tbody[class|style|colspan|rowspan],b[class|style],a[class|style|href|src],p[class|style],-div[id|dir|class|align|style],ins[datetime|cite],-ul[class|style],-li[class|style],code[class|style|contenteditable],img[class|style|src|width|height|data],var[class|style|src|data|contenteditable],hr[class|style], input[style|class|type],textarea[style|class|rows|cols]',
extended_valid_elements: 'input[class|style|type|name|minlength|maxlength|min|max|placeholder|required|ondblclick],textarea[rows|cols|class|style|required]',
toolbar: 'addField ',
pagebreak_separator: '<p style="text-align:center" class="page-break">-------- QUEBRA DE PÁGINA --------</p>',
font_size_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 20pt 24pt 28pt 30pt 36pt 48pt 56pt 70pt 80pt 90pt',
formats: {
  bold: { inline: 'b', 'classes': 'bold' },
  italic: { inline: 'i', 'classes': 'italic' },
  underline: { inline: 'u', 'classes': 'underline', exact: true },
  forecolor: { inline: 'span', classes: 'forecolor', styles: { color: '%value' } },
  hilitecolor: { inline: 'span', classes: 'hilitecolor', styles: { backgroundColor: '%value' } },
},
my_custom_variable: 'test',
line_height_formats: '0 0.5 0.8 1 1.2 1.4 1.6 2',
table_sizing_mode: 'auto',
table_column_resizing: 'resizetable',

setup: (editor) => {

  /* Custom Field button */
  editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('addField', {
    icon: 'paste-row-before',
    tooltip: 'Adicionar campos',
    fetch: function (callback) {

      let fieldoptions = [
        {
          type: 'menuitem',
          text: 'Campo Texto',
          onAction: function () {
            tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
              title: 'Adicionar campo do Tipo Texto',
              level: 'info',
              body: {
                type: 'panel',
                name: 'text_field',
                items: [
                  {
                    type: 'htmlpanel', // an HTML panel component
                    html: edtInputText
                  },
                ]
              },
              buttons: [
                { type: 'cancel', text: 'Fechar' },
                { type: 'submit', buttonType: 'primary', text: 'Inserir campo' }
              ],
              onSubmit: function () {
                let required = $('#imin').val() >= 1 ? 'required' : ''
                editor.insertContent(`<input
                        placeholder="` + $('#iexemp').val() + `"
                        minlength="` + $('#imin').val() + `"
                        maxlength="` + $('#imax').val() + `"
                        name="` + $('#iname').val() + `"
                        ${required}
                        ondblclick="edtField(this)"
                        type="text"
                  /> `)
                tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close()
              }
            })
          }
        }
      ]

      callback(fieldoptions)

    }

  })
  /* End Custom Field button */
 },
}

tinymce.init(editorOpt);
</script>
```

Alguma ideia de como posso editar estes inputs criados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui de uma maneira alternativa.

Dentro do meu javascript criei a função pra abrir a modal assim:

```
edtField = function(ob) { //ob será o elemento do duplo click
    tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        //As options utilizadas na modal.
    });
}
```

E ao inserir um input eu gravo com `dbclick` usando o `parent`, o que faz ele utilizar uma função fora do `iframe` do tinyMCE.

```
ondblclick="parent.edtField(this)"
```